# iOS Periodically perform a low-priority task while the system is idle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, runloop

In the iOS App development process. I want to periodically perform a low priority task. And do not want this task will affect the main program of work. What is the way to achieve it?

Now I use the `timer` to perform periodical task, but often find the App is not smooth.

**The low priority task sometime need run on the main thread, such as check pasteboard than display the content on UI.**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Blocks(Completion handlers) for this, it's part of GCD. This will stay away from main thread.

Make a NSObject class named "**backgroundClass**".

*in .h file*

```
typedef void (^myBlock)(bool success, NSDictionary *dict);

@interface backgroundClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong)  myBlock completionHandler;

-(void)taskDo:(NSString *)userData block:(myBlock)compblock;
```

*in .m file*

```
-(void)taskDo:(NSString *)userData block:(myBlock)compblock{
  // your task here
// it will be performed in background, wont hang your UI. 
// once the task is done call "compBlock" 

compblock(True,@{@"":@""});
}
```

*in your viewcontroller .m class*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
backgroundClass *bgCall=[backgroundClass new];

 [bgCall taskDo:@"" block:^(bool success, NSDictionary *dict){
// this will be called after task done. it'll pass Dict and Success.    

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 // write code here if you need to access main thread and change the UI.
// this will freeze your app a bit.
});

}];
}
```

Comment: This would kind of work, but since you’re dispatching to the main thread it’ll still cause the main thread to block while executing. You should consider using a dispatch queue other than the main queue.

Comment: Depends on how much UI is needed to access, if its very frequent. Yes it will be laggy none the less.

Comment: The task will be repeated and sometime need run on the main thread.
So should consider the frequency of perform, cpu consumption, etc.